# QGIS Dissolve skips polygons

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I'm having trouble with the dissolve function in QGIS. Is it because of an overlap? It's not a GRASS layer, just shapefiles. I'm new with GIS software in general. Searched for similar problems but didn't find anything "monkey proof" so the speak.

Is it because of overlapping polygons? Geometry validity shows multiple errors but can't use v.clean because it's not a GRASS layer.

[image: Situation after dissolving]

Comment: You can perfectly use `v.clean` with shapefiles from the Processing Toolbox

Comment: Thanks, finaly managed to get GRASS up and running and now it worked